# Unable reach another docker container on a port mapped ip address

Tags: docker, networking

I have a CentOS server with two static IP address (192.168.3.100 and 192.168.3.101) on same NIC and two containers running on it with port mapping as below. The containers use the same default 'bridge' network of docker

`192.168.3.100:80->80/tcp  container1`

`192.168.3.101:80->80/tcp  container2`

From the host, I can execute `curl 192.168.3.100` or `curl 192.168.3.101` and works fine. From the host/containers I can execute `curl 172.17.0.2` or `curl 172.17.0.3` and works fine.

But I cannot execute `curl 192.168.3.100` or `curl 192.168.3.101` from neither of these containers. Ends up with error `No route to host`. I can ping it though.

What am I missing here? I want to try to avoid using a 192 docker network as I do not want to tie up the address space with one machine. Using docker 1.12.6

Output for iptables reject rules `iptables -S | grep -i reject`

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Thanks for your input

Comment: can you execute `curl container1` from the other one? Assuming that's the container name. I prefer to use the container/service name when working inside the same network

Comment: yes using the container name itself works because it gets resolved to a 172 net IP address. I would like it to work using the port mapped 192 net IP address since I am planning to assign this for DNS name lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to ping and not able to curl and you get `no route to host` then it mostly means that your packets are getting rejected through firewall.

Check the iptables using `sudo iptables -S` or `sudo iptables -L -n`. If you see a REJECT or REJECT using icmp rule than thats the problem.

If you are not worried about iptables and are ok to clear it. Stop the docker service and run the below

```
$ iptables -F
$ iptables -X
$ iptables -t nat -F
$ iptables -t nat -X
$ iptables -t mangle -F
$ iptables -t mangle -X
```

This will clear all the tables. Then start the docker service and run the container again

Comment: I will need the iptables rules but I can add exceptions to allow packets. Can you please tell if the exception is to be added in FORWARD chain. I am assuming this transfer is from one interface to another which would be part of FORWARD chain

Comment: Print your current chains using `iptables -S | grep -i reject` and add them to your question

Comment: you are right though it was iptables that was blocking it.  `11:37:43.448812 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 9868, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 88)`
`192.168.3.101 > 172.17.0.3: ICMP host 192.168.3.101 unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68`

Comment: I am trying to figure if this rule should be going into DOCKER chain or FORWARD chain and if it'll be persistent. But have not added any working rule yet

Comment: It should be INPUT as per my understanding. Try this `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`